# Building a full world map by collating MKMapview screenshots

Tags: ios, mkmapview, screenshot

I am trying to build a picture of the whole world with a set of overlaid pins on MkMapView.
In order to do so I try to my algorithm is as follow:
take a screenshot
set MkMapRegion to next part of the map not currently on screen
collates all screenshots taken into one big picture.

I have an issue as MkMapView doesn't accurately centre the map on the desired point when I change the latitude, the latitude I set vs the one I end up are different (and varies according to the associated longitude . It's fine for longitude I seem to be able to centre the map on the point I want. Bottom line I have can't seem to be able to re-create the whole world map accurately as I end up with too much or too little of the screenshots vertically.

Anyone with a suggestion?

Code snippet here:

```
   dispatch_queue_t _queue2 = dispatch_queue_create("com.screenShots", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(_queue2, ^{
    int maxLatitudeScreens,maxLongitudeScreens;


    if (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad==UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()){
         maxLatitudeScreens=SCREENS_LATITUDE_IPAD;
        maxLongitudeScreens=SCREENS_LONGITUDE_IPAD;
    }else{
        maxLatitudeScreens=SCREENS_LATITUDE_IPHONE;
        maxLongitudeScreens=SCREENS_LONGITUDE_IPHONE;
    }
     @synchronized(self){
    for (int j=0; j<maxLongitudeScreens;j++){
        for (int i=0 ; i<maxLatitudeScreens; i++) {

            double latitudeDelta=45;
            double longitudeDelta=180;
            double latit=55.0-j*111.0;
            double longit=-180.0+i*longitudeDelta*2/maxLatitudeScreens;

            CLLocationCoordinate2D newCenter= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latit, longit);

            MKCoordinateSpan theSpan= MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
            MKCoordinateRegion theRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(newCenter, theSpan);
            [_contactMapView setRegion:theRegion animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"latit=%f and longit=%f",_contactMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, _contactMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude );
            NSLog(@"mapviewCenterlatitude=%f and longitude=%f",_contactMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, _contactMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude );
             NSLog(@"latitudeSpan=%f and longitudeSpan=%f",_contactMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta, _contactMapView.region.span.longitudeDelta );

            sleep(3);
            [self screenshot:mapViewPrintFormatter.view];
            sleep(1);

        }
    }
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ([self collateImages],nil,nil,nil);
    [self   collateImages];
    [self shareCollatedMapViewImage];

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving the region out of the equation after the original setup? Just move the center using `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` and the zoom should stay consistent.

Comment: I initially tried that to no avail. Using region there seems to be more control as to what element of the map is showed..any other ideas?